# Trying to create a fishing bot in a game. Gettin [error] SyntaxError ( "no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'", )

Tags: python, sikuli

Currently trying to create a fishing bot in a game and running into a roadblock at the end of my try loop which is: `[error] SyntaxError ( "no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'", )`

Here is the code:

```
try:
    if exists("1483151573805.png", 0):
        type(e)
    elif exists("1483151836936.png", 0):
        type(q)
    elif exists("1483151858883.png", 0):
        type(a)
    elif exists("1483151876662.png", 0):
        type(c)
    elif exists("1483151893311.png", 0):
        type(d)
    elif exists("1483151920671.png", 0):
        type(w)
    elif exists("1483151961233.png", 0):
        type(s)
    elif exists("1483151974103.png", 0):
        type(x)
    elif exists("1483152019157.png", 0):
        type(z)
```

Also, what would be the most effective method for looping this?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the loop?

Answer (score 1):

You tagged Sikuli so I'm guessing you're writing a Sikuli script in Python even though you tagged the question as Java. The Jython interpreter uses an ANTLR-generated parser, which prints "no viable alternative at input" when it sees input that violates its grammar rules--the Python grammar rules in this case. It's looking for something at EOF (end of file) and didn't find it. I think you're missing an "except" or "finally" block after your "try" block.

Answer (score 0):

Looking just at the code in your example, you need a `except`. 
 
For example:

```
try:
   #You do your operations here.
except:
   #If there is exception, then execute this block.
```

If you would like some more examples have a look here: [Link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_exceptions.htm)